# Почему не работает фильтр по свойствам класса?

Tags: javascript

Я хочу реализовать метод для фильтрации товаров по указанным опциям. Метод принимает в качестве параметра объект `options`, который содержит параметры для поиска например: `{name: "item 2", price: "<= 1000", count: "> = 2"}`, каждый из параметров является опциональными. Метод должен возвращать отфильтрованный массив с товарами. `filterProductBy (options)`.

**Обязательно: необходимо вытащить параметры из этого объекта через деструктурирование**

```js
//Product Creation Class
class Product {
    constructor(name, count, price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
//Сlass where products are recorded
class Shop {
    constructor(products) {
        this.products = [];
    }
    //method for adding a product
    addProduct(newProduct) {
        this.products.push(newProduct);
    }
    //method for filtering products by specified parameters
    filterProductBy(options) {
        let {name, count, price} = options;
       const getEvaluation = filterString => filterString.indexOf('>=') > -1 ?
        (number, amount) => number >= amount :
        (number, amount) => number <= amount;
        const filteredName = this.products.filter(product => {
            return product.name === undefined || product.name === name
        });
        const filteredCount = this.products.filter(product =>{
            return product.count === undefined ||
                getEvaluation(count)(product.count, count.match(/(\d+)/)[0])
        });
        const filteredPrice = this.products.filter(product =>{
            return product.price === undefined ||
                getEvaluation(price)(product.price, price.match(/(\d+)/)[0])
        });
        return this.products.filter(options);
    }
}
const shop = new Shop();
shop.addProduct(new Product("product 1", 1, 2000));
shop.addProduct(new Product("item 2", 2, 100));
shop.addProduct(new Product("some 3", 3, 500));
shop.addProduct(new Product("anything 4", 4, 1000));
console.log(shop.filterProductBy({
    name: "anything 4",
    count: ">3",
    price: ">=500"
}));
```

Comment: в чем отличие от удаленного вопроса? При частом удалении и перезадании вопросом система может ограничить возможность задавать новые вопросы.

Comment: зачем вы в метод `filter` массива передаете объект опций вашей фильтрации? У вас тут самой фильтрации массива собственно нет. определены настройки, и вроде как какие то функции сравнения. Где сама работа по проверке свойств то? Код, очевидно, не ваш.

Comment: > Почему не работает фильтр по свойствам класса?


 - Потому что вместо функции фильтрации вы передаете объект, о котором встроенный в язык метод `Array.prototype.filter` не имеет ни малейшего понятия

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Сlass where products are recorded
class Shop {
    constructor(products) {
        this.products = [];
    }
    //method for adding a product
    addProduct(newProduct) {
        this.products.push(newProduct);
    }
    //method for filtering products by specified parameters
    filterProductBy(options) {
        const optionName = options.name,
              optionCount = options.count,
              optionPrice = options.price;

        const filters = {
            byName: function (actualName, optionName) {
                // Фильтр будет пройден, если имя продукта (actualName) не задано или равняется optionName
                return (actualName === undefined) || (actualName === optionName);
            },

            byCount: function (actualCount, optionCount) {
                // тут ваша логика
                // заглушка
                return true;
            },

            byPrice: function (actualPrice, optionPrice) {
                // тут ваша логика
                // заглушка
                return true;
            }
        }

        return this.products.filter(
            // функция фильтрации пропустит товар, если все фильтры вернут true
            (product) => filters.byName(product.name, optionName)
                && filters.byCount(product.count, optionCount)
                && filters.byPrice(product.price, optionPrice));
    }
}
```

Добавьте реализацию в методы `filters.byCount` и `filters.byPrice` по аналогии с `filters.byName` и должно заработать.

При желании, объект `filters` можно вынести из тела метода, дабы не создавать его при каждом вызове функции `filterProductBy`.